# ASP.NET MVC : Returning to previous position after postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to return to the previous position on screen after a postback is done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Javascript to include the scroll position in the postback, then use more Javascript to scroll back.

Alternatively, you can just replace the postback with AJAX.